# Send information with url by using an batch

Tags: javascript, batch-file, cookies, cmd, batch-processing

I'm trying to write an Batch, which opens an html file, that adds an cookie to my browser with the content of whoami. 
I want to set the cookie by using javascript.

To now I Got this:

```
set a=%cd%
set a=%a:\=/%
set "user=%USERDOMAIN%\%USERNAME%" 
set "web=file:///%a%/Setzen.html?q=%user%"

start %web%
```

This works fine, but everything after .html is cut.
Theres only "file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/Setzen.html" in my url field.

What I'm doing wrong?

Have you got an better Idea ?

Thank you for your Help

Comment: Did you try `start "%web%"` ?

Answer (score 0):

You must escape special Character ===>
**[Character to be escaped](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php)**

```
@echo off
set a=%cd%
set a=%a:\=/%
set "user=%USERDOMAIN%\%USERNAME%" 
set "web=file:///%a%/Setzen.html^?q=%user%"
echo %web%
start %web%
pause
```

Comment: This doesn't work for my PC.
The content after .html still gets cut.

Comment: For me on my PC, it works and there is not cut at all !